# Serious filename accidents

Tags: command-line, bash

In William Shott's *The Linux Command Line*, Shotts points out that one flaw with Linux is filenames, in that they can almost be anything. So one may name a file `-rf ~` if they wanted to. He then says to consider what would happen if one ran `rm` on that file. So I'm guessing that it would delete all of the user's files in their home directory. But I guess this means that bash cannot distinguish between options and filenames? That seems odd to me.

Comment: `rm -rf~` isn't `rm -rf ~`.

Comment: Sorry I mis-spelled the filename. It should have been `-rf ~` i.e with a space

Comment: The `-rf ~` is not a problem either. A filename with space should be in quotes either way, or escaped by `\\`.

Comment: so you're saying that doing rm `-rf ~` would not delete all files from the home directory? Where `-rf ~` refers to a filename

Comment: Yes it will delete all the files. But you wont run this command to delete `-rf ~` file. You would run `rm "-rf ~"`, or `rm -- -rf\ ~`, or `rm ./-rf\ ~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all files from `~` you need `rm -rf ~`.

Nothing serious would happen with your example. See:

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~/test$ ls
-rf~
pilot6@Pilot6:~/test$:rm -rf~
rm: invalid option -- '~'
Try 'rm ./-rf~' to remove the file '-rf~'.
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
pilot6@Pilot6:~/test$ rm ./-rf~
pilot6@Pilot6:~/test$ ls
pilot6@Pilot6:~/test$
```

Shell treats everything that looks like options as options. So you can't create a file by

```
touch -rf~
```

for example.

Anyway you need to be very careful with spaces when running `rm` command.

See a recent trouble [Ubuntu restored to fabrics(?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194150/ubuntu-restored-to-fabrics/)

If you ask about `-rf ~` file, then it won't be a problem. To remove a file with a space in its name you need either to take it in quotes, or escape the space: `rm "-rf ~"`, or `rm ./-rf\ ~`.

Comment: You can with `touch -- -rf~` though.

Comment: That's what I did ;-)